# Unusual letter combinations

Tags: english, no-computers, letters

<sup>*This is an entry in the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fortnightly-topic-challenge-41-short-and-sweet).*</sup>

---

English spelling is very strange.  Sometimes you encounter words with letter combinations that would seem entirely unpronounceable on their own.

I have listed a few such letter combinations below.  Try to determine what word each combination is from.

- The letters may appear at the beginning, middle or end of the word, but they are all consecutive (no other letters appear in between)
- All words will be found in any reasonable dictionary.  None are particularly obscure.
- In cases where there may be 2 or 3 valid answers, an additional letter has been supplied to disambiguate.  The additional letter must be found *somewhere* in the answer word.
- Since using computers makes this challenge trivial, ***please try to work this one out using only your own brain*** (or those of your friends).

---

**GNAG**
**PSTR (U)**
**KWH**
**NDTHS**
**GHTH (U)**
**CST**
**WKW**
**MBSTR (C)**
**CKKN (F)**
**RWAT (U)**
**NDTHR**
**LFTH**
**RTGA**
**XACE**
**APK**
**ESHOL**

---

When you have all the words, their initials will spell something that English in general, or these words particularly, could use.

Comment: Nice puzzle! Might I ask: How did you come up with your words? A computer search for unique letter combinations, or something else? If you don't want to spoil the secret, you don't need to answer :)

Comment: @DavidKoelle I thought of most of them out of my head.  I then used a computer to check the combinations and ensure that they were unique or almost unique.  For a few of them, I googled "unusually spelled words", and picked a few appropriate words from those lists.

Comment: There were quite a few other words I came up with, which turned out not to be so unique after checking.  I probably went through about 50 words, and ended up with this list.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The **final answer** is

> SUBTLE ADJUSTMENT
>
>  (note that subtle contains the rather rare letter combination BTL. Not sure if that is on purpose ...)

formed by the words

> - Si**gnag**e (Parseltongue)
>  - U**pstr**eam (Parseltongue)
>  - Buc**kwh**eat (Parseltongue)
>  - Thousa**ndths** (Parseltongue)
>  - Li**ghth**ouse (JonMark Perry)
>  - E**cst**atic (Parseltongue)
>
>  - A**wkw**ard (Dorrulf)
>  - Du**mbstr**uck (me, kazi0)
>  - Ja**ckkn**ife (me)
>  - Unde**rwat**er (Dorrulf)
>  - Spe**ndthr**ift (kazi0)
>  - Twe**lfth** (me, kazi0)
>  - Mo**rtga**ge (Dorrulf)
>  - E**xace**rbate (kazi0)
>  - N**apk**in (kazi0)
>  - Thr**eshol**d (Dorrulf)

<sub>I tried to reconstruct who came up with individual words first; which is kind of hard given the timelines and grace period edits. Apologies for any mistakes.</sub>

But if you ask me (non-native speaker here):

> English spelling in general can use a not-so subtle adjustment.

---

I found some remaining ones:

MBSTR:

> duMBSTRuCk

CKKN:

> jaCKKNiFe

LFTH:

> tweLFTH

---

Comment: Really nice answer :)

Comment: Really nice puzzle :)

Comment: But it doesn't contain an F...

Answer (score 10):

Partial answers so far:

> 1. Signage 
>  2. Upstream  
>  3. Buckwheat  
>  4. Thousandths
>  5. *Eighth* (not quite correct, due to disambiguation)
>  6. Ecstatic 
>  7.  
>  8. 
>  9.  
>  10. Overwatch (not quite correct, due to disambiguation). 
>  11. 
>  12. 
>  13. 
>  14. 
>  15. 
>  16. 
>  17. 
>  18. 
>  19. 
>  20

Answer (score 9):

Partial:

> 1.
>  2. UPSTREAM
>  3.
>  4. THOUSANDTHS
>  5.
>  6.
>  7. AWKWARD
>  8.
>  9. ___CKKNIFE
>  10. UNDERWATER
>  11.
>  12.
>  13. MORTGAGE
>  14.
>  15.
>  16. THRESHOLD

Comment: rot13(ahzore 9 vf cebonoyl wnpxxavsr)

Answer (score 8):

Some of the words that haven't been found yet

MBSTR (C):

> dumbstruck

NDTHR:

> spendthrift

LFTH:

> twelfth

XACE:

> exacerbate

APK:

> napkin

Answer (score 5):

5:

> LI**GHTH**OUSE (thanks to the U)