# Unusual letter combinations 2

Tags: word, no-computers, english, language

I really liked [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75131/unusual-letter-combinations) so I made my own version of it!

I'll give you an unusual set of letters which are present consicutively in *one* word* in the English language (and possibly its derivatives, e.g. plural, adverbial form, verbal form, negative form). Your job is to
find that word.
For example, I say `uirr`, and you say... `squirrel`.

Rules are more or less the same than in the first puzzle:

- No word is particularly obscure (I'm a non-native speaker myself.. so please don't hesitate to point out some mistakes!),
- I found these words with some code, but it's to give you the pleasure of looking for them only with your brain (no computers),
- There are no conjugated verbs, and no word necessarily plural,
- No word starts with the set of letters,
- * There may be 2 valid answers for some of these sets, but in that case one word is AFAICT much more uncommon than the other (like "I'd-never-heard-it-before" uncommon). In that case, an additional letter is given in brackets which must appear somewhere in the word (which is the most common one).

---

The sets:

1. **cebe** [g]
2. hq
3. **mcis**
4. eryd
5. **rsda**
6. ekb
7. **mitl**
8. apeg
9. *otew*
10. mnl
11. *ttir*
12. nusu
13. *wada*
14. ptc
15. *cesh* [s]
16. tapo
17. ***etaw***
18. idig
19. ***ptag*** [o]
20. wili
21. ***tebu***
22. rlp [o]
23. ***eswe*** [i]

---

To give this puzzle a "final answer" whiff, here's a bonus : There are three groups of sets written with styling (bold, italic and bold italic). For each of these groups, the initials of the words to be found form *another* unusual set (initials contibute in the order they appear in - eg the set for the bold group is composed of the initials of words 1-3-5-7, in that order).
Finding the new word in which *that* set appears for each styling group will enable you to complete the following sentence:

> I hope my puzzle is not a **word** *word* ***word***.

Comment: To the anonymous editor who [keeps suggesting edits](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/79223/timeline) to this post: the new combinations would spoil the final answer part.

Comment: I am surprised that you included "rsda" and "eryd" in this list, because "rsd" and "ryd" also occur in only one word each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete 23 of 23
Includes answers from Omega Krypton, Bass and Quintec

> ```
>   1  cebe  iceberg
>   2  hq    earthquake
>   3  mcis  circumcism (Quintec)
>   4  eryd  everyday
>   5  rsda  Thursday
>   6  ekb   cheekbone (Quintec)
>   7  mitl  limitless (Bass)
>   8  apeg  scapegoat
>   9  otew  noteworthy
>  10  mnl   solemnly
>  11  ttir  attire (Omega Krypton)
>  12  nusu  unusual
>  13  wada  nowadays
>  14  ptc   bankruptcy (Quintec)
>  15  cesh  spaceship
>  16  tapo  juxtapose,gestapo
>  17  etaw  getaway (Bass)
>  18  idig  prestidigitation (Bass)
>  19  ptag  heptagon (Omega Krypton)
>  20  wili  twilight
>  21  tebu  tastebud (Quintec)
>  22  rlp   whirlpool (Bass)
>  23  eswe  minesweeper (Bass)
> ```

Plus 3 of 3

> ```
>   1..3..5..7  ictl  strictly
>   9-11-13-15  nans  unanswerable
>  17-19-21-23  ghtm  nightmare
> ```

Comment: on th right tracks ! you are correct for 19., which is a synonym, but a more correct version of Omega's proposition. As for 16, I was expecting your first proposition, the second one being a proper noun.

Comment: @Soltius (16) the second was first in mind, but seemed too easy. Regarding proper nouns: (5) is a proper noun.

Comment: Ah, you're right for 5., I got tricked because in my native language, that word (and the other ones of the same type) is not proper  !

Comment: I have put the rest in my answer

Comment: Great job, everyone ! Sorry for the small mistakes !

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer:

Italics:

11:

> attire

Bold Italics:

19:

> septagon

Comment: #19 could be h* instead of s*

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple that are missing from Daniel Mathias's answer:

> 7. mitl - limitless
>  14.  ptc - captcha (?)
>  17. etaw - getaway
>  18. idig - prestidigitation (?)
>  22. rlp - whirlpool
>  23. eswe [i] - minesweeper

Comment: hahaha, wasn't expecting your proposition for 14., it's not in any dictionnary I was using, but I guess it can be accepted ! the three others are correct

Answer (score 3):

Here are most of the the rest - hilarious coincidence that I was pondering the first... (I am not giving that story lol)

> mcis - circumcise (British, I guess) 
>  ekb - cheekbone 
>  ptc - bankruptcy 
>  tebu - is **tastebud** one word somewhere in the world? Looks like one... :P

Comment: For 3., i was thinking of the noun related to the verb you propose, which eliminates AmE/BrE differences.
For 21., it was indeed what I was expecting, present in that form in both dictionnaries I used to make this puzzle.. But I guess they weren't reliable sources because it doesn't seem to exist written that way officialy. Sorry and well done !